# Text of word cloud doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, html, tag-cloud

I try to make a world cloud using TagCanvas [this](http://www.goat1000.com/tagcanvas.php), and it works if I use the following code:

```
<div id="myCanvasContainer">
                <canvas width="690" height="450" id="myCanvas">
                </canvas>
            </div>
            <div id="tags">
                <ul id="tagList">

                    <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Brasil</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/fish"><img src="../front-end/tagcanvas/ola.jpg">Argelia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/chips">Cócò</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/salt">Fìóóó´d´d´d</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/vinegar">Rafa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/vinegar">assim</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/vinegar">ja</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/vinegar">leva</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/vinegar">aqui</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/vinegar">assim</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/vinegar">ja</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/vinegar">leva</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/vinegar">opis</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

but when I use this function:

```
function renderListSelecoes(data) {
var list = data == null ? [] : (data.selecoes instanceof Array ? data.selecoes : [data.selecoes]);
    $('#tagList li').remove();
    $.each(list, function(index, selecaotag) {
        $('#tagList').append('<li><a href="" data-identity="' + selecaotag.id_selecao + '">'+selecaotag.nome+'</a></li>');
    });
}
```

to render the list, the tag canvas doesn't appear, here is part of my code in html:

```
<div class="col-md-8" style="height:500px">
            <div id="myCanvasContainer">
                <canvas width="690" height="450" id="myCanvas">
                </canvas>
            </div>
            <div id="tags">
                <ul id="tagList">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is it because all the lines in the function are commented out?

Comment: No, I fortget to remove the `//`, but still does not work

Comment: how are you calling renderListSelecoes() ??

Comment: Code looks fine. What happens when you `console.log(list)` right after creating it?

Comment: It returns something like this: `[Object, Object, Object, ...]`, and inside of objetc

Comment: It returns something like this: `[Object, Object, Object, ...]`, and inside of object I have `id_selecao = "1", name="Brasil"`

Comment: `nome` or `name`? You might have that mis-typed.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong to write it's `nome="Brasil"`